# Insertion Sort - index is not taking a value

Tags: vb.net, insertion-sort

I am trying to learn how to write an insertion sort, but i have a problem. Index wont take the value of counter.

```
For counter = 1 To length - 1

            temp = arraySort(counter)
            index = counter

            While index > 0 And temp < arraySort(index - 1)

                arraySort(index) = arraySort(index - 1)
                index = index - 1

            End While

            arraySort(index) = temp

        Next
```

I would expect that index would take a value, and it does if I put a breakpoint on the line index = counter, but otherwise no value is taken.

Comment: If what you describe is actually true then it sounds like your VS installation is broken somehow. I suggest that you don't use breakpoints and add some tracing code to test the hypothesis. I would put a `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine` before and after the `While` statement and write out the values of `counter` and `index`. You can then run the code and watch the Output window to see the results. It seems unlikely that `index` will not be set as expected, unless there's some other factor at play

Comment: Probably not the answer, but it wouldn't hurt to declare `counter` explicitly: `For counter As Integer = 1 to length - 1` Also make sure `length` is also explicitly declared as an Integer.

Comment: I have figured it out. I replaced AND with ANDALSO which means if the first statement is not met, the second one is disregarded (as far as I understand). Thank you for your help everyone

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you use `And` or `AndAlso` from the point of view of correctness.  `And` just means that it will access `arraySort(index - 1)` in the case where `index <= 0` but it doesn't look like this should have any visible effects unless `arraySort` is something other than a standard .NET array.